# xcode page-based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create an app based on the page-based application template in xcode 4, that has a title page, table of contents page, and content pages, all formatted differently.  I am new to ios programming, completed the 3 apple tutorials and read a lot of documentation but this is basically my first non-tutorial app.

I'd really appreciate a code example or instructions that shows how to do this properly.  This particular template does not seem to have many examples out there.

specifically:

1. I created a new xcode project and chose the page-based application
   template  (i'm not including the source code here because it should
   be easy to generate for anyone with xcode 4)
2. The template creates an AppDelegate, a RootViewController, a DataViewController and a ModelController
3. For now, I don't care about showing dynamic data. I want the first page to show a view with a label that says "Title" and the
   second page and after to show a text area filled with lorem ipsum.
   I have created a TitlePageView and ChapterView in the storyboard and
   corresponding ViewController files, but do not know how to tie them
   to the DataViewController so that they display.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm not sure how to do it using storyboard, but if you want a simple cut-and-paste solution using nibs, I posted one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687639/542400

Comment: I actually ended up instantiating the sub-view-controllers programmatically using self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: and then adding them as sub-views. seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up putting different views on each page.

1. Create the views for each page in the storyboard, and leave them without a segue or connection to the main page. (you get yellow warning for this)
2. Set the 'identifier' property for each new view to some unique string, e.g. "titlePage"
3. Create an outlet for the big white part of the default page view called "contentArea" in the DataViewController
4. Update the DataViewController class viewWillAppear method to create your page views and add them as sub-views to the contentArea:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       if (_contentArea.subviews.count == 0)
       {
           UIView *pageSubView;
           UIViewController *pageSubViewController;

           pageSubViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"titlePage"];

           [self addChildViewController: pageSubViewController];
           [pageSubViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

           pageSubView = pageSubViewController.view;

           [_contentArea addSubview:pageSubView];
           CGRect pageViewRect = _contentArea.bounds;
           pageSubView.frame = pageViewRect;
        }

   }
   ```

Answer (score -4):

here is the code snippet for creating a page

```
pageInfoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some really useless information on page %d", pageNumber + 1];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with anything? How is setting a labels text anything to do with creating a page?